# How to change format of Date type to another format without converting to String in java

Tags: java, date, datetime

I want to change the format of date type object without converting to String type.

Currently I'm getting the date object then changing the format after that converting it to date object again but the format changes.

Here is my code

```
Date dateOld = issuebean.getCusDtl().getDob();
System.out.println(dateOld);
```

output1: 1955-01-24 00:00:00.0

After that I am changing the format

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter=  new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String format1 = formatter.format(dateOld);
System.out.println(format1);
```

output2: 24-01-1955

After that I am parsing it into date object

```
Date format2 = formatter.parse(format1);
System.out.println(format2);
```

But now the output is output3: Mon Jan 24 00:00:00 IST 1955

I want output2 in date object format2 because I need to set date object in my class.

Comment: A `Date` object doesn't have a _format_. It is a date (and time) information. The formatting simply comes from the ... uhhmmm ... formatter.

Comment: so how can i get desired output?

Comment: I thought, I said that: _Use the formatter!_ You already did that for the second output. Why are you so confused in the third output?

Comment: i am using formatter..  Date format2 = formatter.parse(format1);

Comment: Ok, sorry. In this line you are _parsing_ a string to a date object. By "use the formatter" I meant, you should use the formatter to _format_ a date. Like you did in line `String format1 = formatter.format(dateOld);`. Maybe you got confused by your own variable naming, because you named a date variable `format2`. In the first example, your variable `format1` is a string-typed variable.

Comment: You're just `parsing` a string to the Date object, you should `format` it instead like you did the first time.

Comment: but after formatting i am getting output in as String but i want in Date type object

Comment: You can Extend `Date` class and override the `toString()` method  as per your liking.

Comment: can you do please i  am unable to do

Comment: You can either **display** the date, which means it is converted to a string, or **use** the date (compare it to other dates, get its milliseconds value). To use it as a date, you use the actual date object. But for display purposes, you *always* convert it to a string - whether explicitly by calling its `toString()` or using a `DateFormat`, or implicitly, when you print - it uses the `toString()` function. So there is no way to change its format without converting to a string. For displaying, always use a formatter, get the string and display it. So do you need to *display* it or *use* it?

Comment: i want to set output2 in my setter method which is of type Date.

Comment: @artle Please be careful with Tags on your Question. This Question has nothing to do with JavaScript nor Hibernate that I can see.

Answer (score 1):

A [`DateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) is a *tool* to convert a `Date` to a `String` (method `format`) **or** a `String` to a `Date` (method `parse`). Read the javadoc for more informations

When you print a `Date` with `System.out.println`, the `toString()` method of `Date` is used to do the transformation `Date` > `String`, if you don't want that, you have to do the transformation by yourself, using a call to `DateFormat#format()`  (for example)

Answer (score 0):

## Abusing java.util.Date Inheritance

The format of your output1 suggests you have improperly used a java.sql.Timestamp as a java.util.Date.

Here is some example code as evidence.

```
java.sql.Timestamp sqlTimestamp = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf ( "2015-01-23 00:00:00" );
java.util.Date improperUtilDate = sqlTimestamp;  // Do NOT do this. Docs warn against using this inheritance relationship.
java.util.Date properUtilDate = new java.util.Date ();

System.out.println ( "sqlTimestamp: " + sqlTimestamp + " | improperUtilDate: " + improperUtilDate + " | properUtilDate: " + properUtilDate );
```

> sqlTimestamp: 2015-01-23 00:00:00.0 | improperUtilDate: 2015-01-23 00:00:00.0 | properUtilDate: Sun Dec 13 12:27:22 PST 2015

While technically java.sql.Timestamp is a subclass of java.util.Date, the documentation tells you to ignore that fact and consider them separate. This class design was a hack, an unfortunate choice made during the rush to get Java to market in the early years.

## Date-Time != String

The [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34223898/642706) by RC. is correct. Date-time objects do not have a "format". You seem to be conflating the date-time object with a generated String representation of that value.

You can parse a String to get a date-time object. And a date-time object can be used to generate a String that represents the date-time value. The date-time object and the String are always separate unrelated objects.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later supplants the troublesome old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes. The new classes are inspired by the highly successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) framework, intended as its successor, similar in concept but re-architected. Defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. See the [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

### Convert From java.sql To java.time

Use the java.sql.* classes (java.sql.Timestamp, java.sql.Date, etc.) only to get date in/out of the database. Then convert to java.time as soon as possible. Eventually JDBC drivers will be updated to use java.time types directly. But until that day we must convert.

```
java.sql.Timestamp sqlTimestamp = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf ( "2015-01-23 00:00:00" );
Instant instant = sqlTimestamp.toInstant ();
```

### Time Zone

From there you want the date only, without time-of-day. To determine a date, we need apply a time zone. Date only has meaning within a particular time zone. For example, a new day dawns earlier in Paris than in Montréal, and even earlier in Kolkata.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "Asia/Kolkata" );  // For UTC, use the constant ZoneOffset.UTC.
```

Apply that time zone to get a `ZonedDateTime`. From there we can extract a date-only object, a `LocalDate`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant ( instant , zoneId );
LocalDate localDate = zdt.toLocalDate ();
```

### Formatter

Now find or define a formatter to guide the generation of a String representation of that `LocalDate` object’s value.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "dd-MM-yyyy" ); // Or better yet, let java.time determine a localized format.
String output = localDate.format ( formatter );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "sqlTimestamp: " + sqlTimestamp + " = instant: " + instant + " in zoneId: " + zoneId + " is zdt: " + zdt + " with localDate: " + localDate + " as output: " + output );
```

> sqlTimestamp: 2015-01-23 00:00:00.0 = instant: 2015-01-23T08:00:00Z in zoneId: Asia/Kolkata is zdt: 2015-01-23T13:30+05:30[Asia/Kolkata] with localDate: 2015-01-23 as output: 23-01-2015